# Nested class crash C++

Tags: c++, class, nested

Main.cpp

```
#include <string>

#include "Test.h"
#include "Test.cpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace Classes;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Test test("bar");   

    return 0;
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

namespace Classes {

    class Test::Implementation {
        string mFoo;
        friend class Test;
    };

    Test::Test(string foo) {
        setFoo(foo);
        i = new Test::Implementation();
    }

    Test::~Test() {

    }

    string Test::getFoo() {
        return i->mFoo;
    }

    void Test::setFoo(string foo) {
        i->mFoo = foo;
    }
}
```

Test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

using namespace std;

namespace Classes {

    class Test {

        private:
            class Implementation;
            Implementation *i;

        public:
            friend class Implementation;

            Test(string foo);
            ~Test();

            string getFoo();
            void setFoo(string foo);

    };
}

#endif
```

I am trying to work with nested classes in C++.
When I compile this application I get a problem: "Main.exe has stopped working"
I can't find the problem. But I know that my app crashes then I try to do `i->mFoo`. Maybe someone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You didn't provide a declaration for `class Implementation;` only a forward declaration.

Comment: Time to load up your debugger.

Comment: BTW it is not clear why you wouldn't just make Test class an abstract interface, then implement everything in Test_Implementation, which is derived from that interface. That looks typical way for hiding Implementation from users of Test class. I will assume that your actual use case is more complex - otherwise consider just using interfaces .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Test::Test()` constructor you are calling `setFoo()` before initializing `i`, so `i` is uninitialized at that point and trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer is causing your crash.  Simply swap those two lines around, so that `i` is initialized first.

You will also want to add `delete i;` to the `Test::~Test()` destructor, otherwise the memory for `i` will be leaked.